# What is the neatest way to remove all but the last item from a list in groovy?

Tags: groovy

I've been trying to find a neat way to remove all but the last element from a list in groovy, but all the things I've tried seem a bit overcomplicated.  Is there a neater way?

FAILS: `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`

```
void removeAllButLastInPlace(list) {
    if(list.size() > 1) {
        def remove = list[0..-2]
        remove.each { list.remove(it) }
    }
}
```

FAILS: `java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException: java.util.ArrayList$SubList`

```
void removeAllButLastInPlace(list) {
    if(list.size() > 1) {
        def remove = list[0..-2].clone()
        remove.each { list.remove(it) }
    }
}
```

WORKS, but list construction seems unnecessary

```
void removeAllButLastInPlace(list) {
    if(list.size() > 1) {
        def remove = [] + list[0..-2]
        remove.each { list.remove(it) }
    }
}
```

WORKS, but seems a bit arcane

```
void removeAllButLastInPlace(list) {
    (list.size() - 1).times { list.remove(0) }
}
```

WORKS, perhaps most 'correct'

```
void removeAllButLastInPlace(list) {
    list.retainAll { list.lastIndexOf(it) == list.size() - 1 }
}
```

The code should fulfil the following tests:

```
list = []
removeAllButLastInPlace(list)
assert list == []

list = ['a']
removeAllButLastInPlace(list)
assert list == ['a']

list = ['a', 'b']
removeAllButLastInPlace(list)
assert list == ['b']

list = ['a', 'b', 'c']
removeAllButLastInPlace(list)
assert list == ['c']
```

Comment: I don't have enough rep to downvote but maybe it stands because of you've not thanked to people who are trying to help you, in anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than mutating an existing list., why not return a new list?

Then you can simply do:

```
List removeAllButLast( List list ) {
  list ? [list[-1]] : []
}
```

Or:

```
List removeAllButLastInPlace( List list ) {
  list.drop( list.size() - 1 )
}
```

#### edit:

You could also use a loop (if you have to have a mutating method)

```
void removeAllButLastInPlace( List list ) {
   while( list.size() > 1 ) list.remove( 0 )
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that.  In this particular instance I specifically want to modify the list instance.

Comment: Fair enough, just so long as you're aware that it potentially makes your code less favorable to concurrency.

Comment: I'm aware and happy with that - this particular code is for use in a shell script.

Comment: Ok. Though code often ends up neater when it's immutable. Have fun.

Comment: Thanks, and it's a useful note (neatness and concurrency).  In this particular case though, reassigning the reference is not possible.

Comment: @Alison added a mutating version which uses a loop at the end

Comment: @Alison Don't forget, it won't be very efficient if the list grows to being massive... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
void removeAllButLastInPlace( List list ) {
    def index = 0
    list.reverse(true).retainAll({index++ == 0})
}
```

Comment: This will fail if the list contains duplicates

Comment: That wil now just reverse the list (`take` does not mutate the list, so just returns a new list containing a single element which is discarded by the above method)

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for one of these.  My criteria being a) modifying the list in place as stated in your requirement (not returning a new list) and b) succinctness.

I have however made both versions return a reference to the modified list just to simplify the `println` examples.  You could make the return type 'void' if preferred and remove the last 'xs' line from each.

```
def xs1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
def xs2 = [9]
def xs3 = []

def keepOnlyLast1(xs) {
    while(xs.size() > 1) xs.remove(0)
    xs
}

def keepOnlyLast2(xs) {
    xs[0 ..< xs.size()-1] = []
    xs
}

println "Version 1"
println keepOnlyLast1([] + xs1)
println keepOnlyLast1([] + xs2)
println keepOnlyLast1([] + xs3)

println "Version 2"
println keepOnlyLast2([] + xs1)
println keepOnlyLast2([] + xs2)
println keepOnlyLast2([] + xs3)

/* Sanity check that these methods *really* modify the list. */
println "Sanity Check"
keepOnlyLast1(xs1)
println xs1
keepOnlyLast2(xs2)
println xs2
```

Aside: I would also go for a more functional style if at all possible (i.e. return a new list rather than modifying the existing one) except that that wasn't what you asked for.  Here's an example anyway:

```
def lastAsList(xs) {
    xs.isEmpty() ? [] : [xs[-1]]
}
println lastAsList([1, 2, 3])
println lastAsList([])
```